# ValueError Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Product:name>]

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am a student learning Django. I want to implement so that I receive the product code in the order(join model) DB when ordering a product, but it is difficult because I keep getting an error like the title. I think I will die because it hasn't been solved for too long.
When I use product.object.all(), all the query sets are loaded, and even when I use a filter, an error occurs. How can I solve this problem? It would be such an honor if you could reply.

**Error Message**

> ValueError at /join/element_detail/ Cannot assign "<QuerySet
> [<Product: 학잠>, <Product: 헤라 블랙쿠션>, <Product: 종근당 활력 비타민B>, <Product:
> 코디 순수 3겹데코>, <Product: 다이어리>, <Product: 화이트 스탠드 조명>, <Product: 파이썬 웹
> 프로그래밍 교재>, <Product: 나이키 후드집업>]>": "Join.product_code" must be a
> "Product" instance.

```
join / views.py

join.product_code = product
```

This part appears to be the problem.

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='username')
    category_code = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=False, allow_unicode=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    benefit = models.TextField()
    detail = models.TextField()
    target_price = models.IntegerField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
    due_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['product_code']
        index_together = [['product_code', 'slug']]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('zeronine:product_detail', args=[self.product_code, self.slug])


class Join(models.Model):
    join_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='username')
    product_code = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='product_code')
    part_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.join_code)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['join_code']
```

*****My guess is that there is something wrong with this part.(join/views.py)
I think something went wrong in the process of receiving the product, but I don't know how.*****

**join/views.py**

```
def element_detail(request):
    designated_object = Designated.objects.all()
    element_object = Element.objects.all()
    value_object = Value.objects.all()
    product = Product.objects.all()

    if request.method == "POST":
            join = Join()
            join.product_code = product
            join.username = request.user
            join.part_date = timezone.now()
            join.save()


            return render(request, 'zeronine/list.html')


    return render(request, 'zeronine/detail.html', {'designated_object': designated_object,
                                                    'element_object': element_object,
                                                    'value_object': value_object})
```

**zeronine/views.py**

```
def product_in_category(request, category_slug=None):
    current_category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.all()

    if category_slug:
        current_category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category_code=current_category)

    return render(request, 'zeronine/list.html', {'current_category': current_category,
                                                  'categories':categories,
                                                  'products':products})

def product_detail(request, id, product_slug=None):
    current_category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.all()
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, product_code=id, slug=product_slug)
    designated_object = Designated.objects.filter(rep_price='True')
    element_object = Element.objects.all()
    value_object = Value.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'zeronine/detail.html', {'product':product,
                                                    'products':products,
                                                    'current_category': current_category,
                                                    'categories':categories,
                                                    'designated_object': designated_object,
                                                    'element_object':element_object,
                                                    'value_object':value_object})
```

**zeronine/detail.html**

```
        <form method="POST" style="margin-left: 110px;" action="{% url 'zeronine:element_detail' %}">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="value_code" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"><b>옵션</b></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <select type="text" class="form-control" name="value_code" id="value_code">
                                {% for value in value_object %}
                                {%if value.product_code == product %}
                                    <option value="{{value.value_code}}">{{value.name}}</option>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                {% csrf_token %}
                 {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
                <a onclick="alert('로그인 후 참여가 가능합니다.');" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <button type="submit" style="background:black; border-color:black;" class="btn btn-primary">&nbsp;참여하기</button></a>

                <a onclick="alert('로그인 후 찜하기가 가능합니다.');" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <button type="submit" style="background:white; color:black; border-color:black;" class="btn btn-primary">찜하기</button></a>

                  {% else %}
                <a onclick="alert('{{ product.name }} 공동구매 참여가 완료되었습니다.');" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <button type="submit" action="{% url 'zeronine:element_detail' %}" style="background:black; border-color:black;" class="btn btn-primary">&nbsp;참여하기</button></a>
                <a onclick="alert('{{ product.name }} 상품을 찜했습니다.');" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <button type="submit" style="background:white; color:black; border-color:black;" class="btn btn-primary">찜하기</button></a>
                  {% endif %}
            </form>
```

Comment: Can you show all the error message you received?

Comment: @Martins Added error messages and problematic parts to the text!

Comment: I think you are trying to add a queryset "product" to the Join model field "product_code" which is a ForegnKey to Product Model. Try Doing something Like this ` product = Product.objects.first()

    if request.method == "POST":
            join = Join()
            join.product_code = product
            join.username = request.user
            join.part_date = timezone.now()
            join.save()`

Comment: if you are trying to add a single object to the `Join()`, use get. ".filter() and .all()" as there name suggests will return a qureyset and not an object instance.

Comment: @Martins Only one product has been ordered correctly. But I'm crying because I'm so happy that the data was entered into the DB. What should I do to order all the products? I'd appreciate it if you could give me an answer.

Comment: Are you adding multiple products to Join() models?

Comment: @Martins There are several products in the product model. I need to get various products from join. However, now only one product is stored, not multiple products, and if you try to purchase another product, you will get an error "Product matching query does not list."

Comment: Check the commented section of the view edited answer... hope this helps, because I'm not quite sure what you wanted to do.

Comment: @Martins I was able to solve the problem as a result of writing the code by referring to what you said and thinking about the error. I think you're a great developer. Thank you. I hope you have a good day.

Comment: I'm glad you could solve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    def element_detail(request):
        designated_object = Designated.objects.all()
        element_object = Element.objects.all()
        value_object = Value.objects.all()
        product = Product.objects.all()
    
        if request.method == "POST":
                product_id = request.POST.get('value_code') # new
                product = Product.objects.get(product_code=product_id) # new
# Or 
        #product_ids = request.POST.getlist('value_code')
        #products = Product.objects.filter(product_code__in=product_ids)
        #loop all products and save example;
        #for product in products:
        #   join = Join()
        #   join.product_code = product
        #   join.username = request.user
        #   join.part_date = timezone.now()
        #   join.save()
                join = Join()
                join.product_code = product
                join.username = request.user
                join.part_date = timezone.now()
                join.save()
    
    
                return render(request, 'zeronine/list.html')
```

Edited to include multiple values from template, I'm assuming of course.